# C++ Multithreading Issue

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, ifstream, std

I have following algorithm to work with a file:

```
//open ifstram to read each line

//open ofstream to output each line

while (getline(ifstream, line1)){

getline(ifstream, line2) ;
getline(ifstream, line3) ;  
getline(ifstream, line4) ;
//
getline(ifstream, line10) ;

for(int i = 1 ; i <= 10 ; i++)
// process line number i (some sort of character replacement, substring extraction)

output each line

}
```

Now, to make my code faster I want to perform multithreading. However, I can't understand, how to run the above algorithm using multiple thread thus I will get faster & correct output. Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: If you hope to get an answer, you should provide some working code - this isn't. If you don't, your question is likely to be closed.

Comment: Actually, I am not getting how to run above algoritm in multiple thread. I have to perform lots of I/O, I am not getting how to make I/Os thread independent.

Comment: @user1838343: You can't really encapsulate all the knowledge you need for that in a single Q&A. You need to read a ton of books.

Answer (score 2):

1. Multithreading doesn't necessarily lead to faster programs.
2. Whether or not this *can* be done depends on what kind of processing you do there. If it's something that's done per string and doesn't depend on previous result, you could use std::future in C++11. If you don't want to use C++11, specify what you *do* want to use.
3. You can't lead multiple lines in parallel from a serial stream, if that's what you're trying to do. The reason should be obvious.

Comment: Actually, I want to read line 1-10, 20-30 by thread 1 and line 10-20,30-40 by thread 2. Is this possible ? And how to output that in same file ?

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work.

Comment: +1  There is overhead with thread comms. To make that overhead worthwhile, the parcel of work communicated should be substantial.  10 lines of text is insignificant.  10000 lines of text *might* make it worth while.

Comment: @MartinJames, I have millions of lines. My code will iterate over every 10 lines of text.

Comment: The code reading the lines won't be the bottleneck. Read your file in 10 line blocks, and then start a new thread with the result. If whatever you're doing with these ten lines is inexpensive though, you won't gain much if anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to read from a stream and do processing of the read material in chunks.

There are several opportunities for parallelization in this example.

1. If you are reading from a file, the OS can continue reading the file's contents into a buffer while you are processing the first chunks.
2. If the source you are reading from is not truly linear, you can create multiple streams and several workers, each working on their own set of chunks.
3. In the case that you cannot control the source of the data, the next opportunity is to have a single I/O thread that puts the read chunks into some kind of queue which drives any number of workers. This is similar to #2, but the splitting happens within your process. This can be helpful e.g. if you need to preserve the order between chunks, in which case a single output worker would collect the chunks in a queue again and sort and output them as they arrive.

Which one of those is actually applicable to your situation can only be determined by you. Also, depending on the ratio of I/O to required processing and threading overhead, the solution #3 might be

- harmful (high threading overhead compared to low I/O and low processing costs)
- only useful with a single worker (low threading overhead and processing costs less than I/O; in this case, the single worker will finish processing before the next chunk is read)
- limited by the number of cores in your platform (low threading overhead and I/O costs, but high processing; in this case, additional workers will only jostle for limited resources, like caches, which leads to unnecessary inefficiencies)